# How to correctly get mouse events in react without re-rendering the parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to make a hook that returns the `clientX` and `clientY` values when the mouse moves on the screen. My hook looks like this -

### useMouseMove hook

```
const useMouseMove = () => {
    const [mouseData, setMouseData] = useState<[number, number]>([0, 0])

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleMouse = (e: MouseEvent) => {
            setMouseData([e.clientX, e.clientY])
        }

        document.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouse)

        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouse)
        }
    }, [])

    return mouseData
}
```

And I'm using it in another component like so,

### Usage in component

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
    const mouseData = useMouseMoveLocation()

    console.log("Rendered") // I want this to be rendered only once

    useEffect(() => {
        // I need to use the mouseData values here
        console.log({ mouseData })
    }, [mouseData])

    return <>{/* Some child components */}</>
}
```

I need to use the `mouseData` values from the `useMouseMove` hook in the parent component (named SomeComponent in the above example) **without re-rendering** the entire component every time the mouse moves across the screen. Is there a correct way to do this to optimise for performance?

Comment: Well, you can store the values in a ref instead of state, but if you're not rerendering, then your useEffect is not going to be running. Can you be more specific about what you plan to do in the useEffect?

Comment: Hi @NicholasTower I am animating a three.js model inside the useEffect. The model loads once when the component mounts in a separate useEffect with an empty array deps. So I only need to animate it using the mouseData values. I am trying to avoid re-rendering everytime state changes due to mouseMove. With refs, AFAIK the useEffect doesn't detect ref.current changes so I can't use it :(

Comment: `With refs, AFAIK the useEffect doesn't detect ref.current changes so I can't use it` Correct, but it's broader than that: If you're not rendering, then a useEffect will not run. ref's are just an example of something that doesn't cause rendering.

Comment: Understood, thank you so much for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not going to be rendering this component, then you can't use a useEffect. useEffect's only get run if your component renders. I think you'll need to run whatever code you have in mind in the `mousemove` callback:

```
const useMouseMove = (onMouseMove) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove)

        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove)
        }
    }, [onMouseMove])
}

const SomeComponent = () => {
  useMouseMove(e => {
    // do something with e.clientX and e.clientY
  });
}
```